# Need to display records which has positive and negative value

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data in my table

> ```
> ID     code     date        amount   health_plan
> 111    A123     20170101     10      BH
> 111    A123     20100101    -10      BH
> 311    A124     20170712     20      CVA
> 311    A124     20170712    -20      CVA
> 311    A124     20170712     20      CVA
> 311    A124    20180201      55      CVA
> ```

I create a query to display those records who has both positive and negative   values for the same ID, code and date. After running the following   query I am expecting this type of output.

> ```
> 111    A123    20170101      10      BH
> 111    A123    20100101     -10      BH
> 311    A124    20170712      20      CVA
> 311    A124    20170712     -20      CVA
> ```

```
WITH amt_cur
        AS (SELECT DISTINCT first_name,
                            last_name,
                            birth_date,
                            gender,
                            health_plan,
                            id,
                            code,
                            date,
                            amount
            FROM   table_a
            WHERE  (id,
                    code,
                    date,
                    health_plan) IN
                      (SELECT a.id,
                              a.code,
                              a.date,
                              a.health_plan
                       FROM   table_a a
                              JOIN table_a b
                                 ON     b.health_plan = a.health_plan
                                    AND b.id = a.id
                                    AND b.date = a.date
                                    AND b.code = a.code
                                    AND b.amount <> a.amount
                                    AND (a.amount > 0 AND b.amount < 0)))
SELECT *
FROM   amt_cur
ORDER BY id, code, date;
```

But I am getting the following output

> ```
> 111    A123     20170101      10       BH
> 111    A123     20100101     -10       BH
> 311    A124     20170712      20       CVA
> 311    A124     20170712     -20       CVA
> 311   A124      20170712      20       CVA
> ```

Can someone help to achieve the results?

Comment: Your data missing `health_plan`, and this is important to understand how your query should work.

Comment: When both positive and negative amount exist for the same (id, code, date) combination, are they always the same (in absolute value, e.g. +10 and -10) or can they be diffrerent (+10 and -17)? Do they always come in pair (one negative and one positive)?

Comment: Negative and positive values might be change. When the outcome of both amount = 0 then I have to display those records. For example if I have +10 and -17 then the outcome is -7 which is don't need to display.

Comment: So: your sample data has a duplicate row. Row #5 from the top is identical (same values in all columns) to Row #3. Are you saying that your requirement, in addition to what you said, is to **also** remove duplicates? Otherwise it is not clear why the output you are getting with your existing query is "incorrect" - it looks perfectly fine to me. What if the value in row #5 from the top wasn't 20, but 40? Would you, then, want all three rows, from #3 to #5, in the output? If not, what additional rule is there?

Answer (score 2):

How about simply using `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.amount < 0) and
      exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.amount > 0) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH amt_cur
        AS (SELECT MAX(first_name) first_name,
                            MAX(last_name) last_name,
                            MAX(birth_date) birth_date,
                            MAX(gender) gender,
                            health_plan,
                            id,
                            code,
                            "date",
                            amount
            FROM   table_a
            WHERE  (id,
                    code,
                    "date",
                    health_plan,
                    ABS(amount)) IN
                      (SELECT distinct a.id,
                              a.code,
                              a."date",
                              a.health_plan,
                              ABS(a.amount)
                       FROM   table_a a
                              JOIN table_a b
                                 ON     b.health_plan = a.health_plan
                                    AND b.id = a.id
                                    AND b."date" = a."date"
                                    AND b.code = a.code
                                    AND ABS(b.amount + a.amount) < 0.00001
                                    AND (a.amount > 0 AND b.amount < 0))
  GROUP BY health_plan, id, code, "date", amount
                                    )
SELECT *
FROM   amt_cur
ORDER BY id, code, "date";
```

Comment: But is also an important element of compare. Date should be same for both negative and positive amount. Also the logic is something like to display b.amount + a.amount = 0. So for example if we have 10, -10 and 10 amount for the given Id, code, health_plan and date then it will only display 10 and -10 because the outcome is 0.

Comment: The comparison of b.amount + a.amount = 0 is currently missing. As mention in a comment above can you add health_plan to the sample data.

Comment: I try the logic b.amount + a.amount = 0 in my query but it is not working. That's why I ask this question.

Comment: because the amount is also important for the query I have now added it to the where selection as absolute value. And I added the amount comparison that works when I run it on my db instance.

Comment: is the amount column of typ integer or a floating point data type? Then you should compare it by "AND ABS(b.amount + a.amount) < 0.00001"

Comment: what data type is amount? Have you seen that I have edit the query and add amount also to the where clause IN statement?

Comment: @ Raphael. I try your code but still I am getting all three records in the output. 
For example I have the following records in my table for a particular ID 

ID    code   DATE       amount health_plan
311   A124   20170712   20     CVA
311   A124   20170712  -20     CVA
311   A124   20170712   20     CVA

I am expecting the following outcome 

ID    code   DATE       amount health_plan
311   A124   20170712   20     CVA
311   A124   20170712  -20     CVA

Comment: Datatype is Number.

Comment: are the columns first_name, last_name, birth_date and gender are identical for all rows?

Comment: Yes, first_name, last_name, birth_date and gender are identical for all rows.

Comment: Your query is working well for example if i have -10, 10 and 10 amount then I will only return 10 and -10 but when I have -10, 10 and 15 then it is not working. Display all three records.

Comment: Its working now :). I did a little tweak and its working. Thanks for you help @Raphael.

Answer (score 0):

This query retrieves data according to your rules:

```
with t as (
   select a.* , count(distinct a.amount)over(partition by a.id,a."DATE",a.code,a.health_plan) "count"
    , sum (a.amount) over(partition by a.id,a."DATE",a.code,a.health_plan) "sum"
   from table_a a
)
select a.id,a.code,a."DATE",a.amount
from t a  where "count">1 and "sum"=0
;
```

Currently it produces nothing, because none of your data matches the rules.
The first two rows have different dates, the three next has sum !=0 , and the last does not have a pair.