# Spark - Find rows with same ID but values with opposite sign

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have a spark dataset with 2 columns - id & value.

It may have some values with same id but values with opposite sign (same absolute value). For example,

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| a | 5 |
| b | 10 |
| a | -5 |
| b | 10 |
| a | 5 |
| b | 10 |
| a | -5 |
| b | 5 |
| a | 5 |
| b | 1 |

My use-case is to flag all such pairs of rows where ID is same but one value is positive and the other is negative (but absolute value is same). For example:

| id | value | flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 5 | true |
| b | 10 | true |
| a | -5 | true |
| b | -10 | true |
| a | 5 | true |
| b | 10 | false |
| a | -5 | true |
| b | 5 | false |
| a | 5 | false |
| b | 1 | false |

Please note that one positive value must be paired with at most one other negative value and vice versa.

I came across a solution in SQL (might need some modifications but the idea is similar): [Need to display records which has positive and negative value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49030474/need-to-display-records-which-has-positive-and-negative-value)

But since I’m new to spark, I’m not able to convert it into an equivalent spark code. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sankar, I've added my answer in scala, let me know if you need pyspark or Java eqvivalent

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
df.alias("t1").join(df.alias("t2"), (col("t1.id")===col("t2.id")) && (col("t1.value")===col("t2.value").*(-1)), "left")
.withColumn("Flag", when(col("t2.id").isNull, "false").otherwise("true"))
.select("t1.*", "Flag")
.show()
```

Input:

[image: Input]

Output:

[image: Output]